# C -- Print To Screen Without #include <stdio.h>?

Tags: c

Is there a way to have a `C` source file print to the screen without including `<stdio.h>`?

Here's my situation: I was asked to *programatically* handle 1000 `C` source files that will each implements several numerical functions in `C` (these functions are supposed to work on data that is ***in memory***, eithout any I/O). The origin of these source files in unclear, and hence, I'd like to make sure there will be no harm to my machine when I compile & run these source files.

Is there a way to find out if a `C` source file is potentially harmful? I thought of asking the developers to avoid any `#include` statements whatsoever, but I do need just `printf` -- as I'd like them to include an output of their calculations within `main()`.

Any ideas?

Comment: can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: Well, there's always `#error` if you feel like using the preprocessor...  Why do you want to avoid `<stdio.h>`?

Comment: You could run the code through a static analyzer, like lint.

Comment: I'd use a virtual machine to run the tests in - maybe even fire up some old box gathering dust in the closet that can get wiped & reinstalled (or just wiped and put back in the closet) when the job is done.

Comment: Another thing I'd do is run the programs under a user account that has pretty much no permissions to the file system or network. I'd still do it in a VM or sacrificial box though.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Harmful C Source File Check?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6810322/harmful-c-source-file-check)

Comment: Due to the edits changing the purpose of the question, the title should be changed, the accepted answer dropped as its of only limited relevance in disproving the old premise, and one of the VM or alternate user answers chosen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, add the prototype for `printf` at the top of your source file, as long as you're linking to the CRT libraries you can use the function without including `stdio.h`

`printf` prototype

```
int printf ( const char * format, ... );
```

Answer (score 3):

There are, though they are probably a bit larger than the scope of the format of SO. In essence you leverage assembler calls in C. The blog [KSplice](http://blogs.oracle.com/ksplice/) touches on the subject ( with code and examples ) [here](http://blogs.oracle.com/ksplice/entry/hello_from_a_libc_free).

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way to find out if a C source file is potentially harmful?

No, there is none. A malicious source file could possibly do anything it wanted by defining its own prototypes, or by using inline assembly -- `#include` is just a compile-time convenience.

Comment: duskwuff, I can check for the existence of `asm` in the source `c` file -- if it exists, it means inline assembly is used; What am I missing?

Comment: There's tons of other indirect ways to do subversive things in C. Putting assembly in a byte buffer, casting it to a function pointer, and calling it; `dlsym()`; intentionally causing buffer overflows; hiding any of these things behind preprocessor tricks… all in all, there is no way to verify that some source code isn't hiding something up its sleeve.

Comment: duskwuff, thank you. Can you give me at least *some keywords* to help me be say 95% safe? things like `asm`, `dlsym`, `#` -- when it DOES NOT follow `include` etc. I just want to do **something** to be more safe, even if not 100%.

Comment: What you're trying to do is called "static analysis", and it's basically impossible without placing major restrictions on what code is allowed to do (e.g, no pointers/arrays).

Comment: duskwuff, thank you. I am OK with placing some restrictions. The question is, how do I do it / where do I start? I asked another question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6810322/harmful-c-source-file-check

Answer (score 2):

I would like to clarify why we need printf and studio.h to maybe make the concept more clear. C is a portable language. You can compile c for Linux, Mac OSX, Windows. In each, causing  output normally boils down to a system call, or in embedded systems, dealing directly with a frame buffer or Uart device.

So of course it is possible, do you want to do it? Depends why. If you are coding against a specific platform and dont have printf(), then you may have to look into invoking a system call directly for that platform/writing some platform specific assembly code. It all depends on your use case.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, put the necessary function prototypes in your program.

If you mean by not using printf, then you have several options - you can use fwrite, or you could dispense with streams and use write, or you could invoke operating system I/O services directly, or perhaps you could talk to the display hardware directly, or many other things.

If you want a better answer, perhaps explain why you want to not include stdio.h

Answer (score -5):

This is silly but still:

```
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    puts ("hi");
return 0;
}
```

and Output:

```
$ gcc -o try try.c 
$ ./try 
hi
```

Comment: `puts()` is actually defined in `<stdio.h>`, not `<string.h>`.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. Anyhow my answer doesn't make sense after OP described the question :D