# Harmful C Source File Check?

Tags: c, static-analysis

Is there a way to **programmatically** check if a single `C source file` is potentially harmful?

I **know** that no check will yield 100% accuracy -- but am interested *at least* to do some basic checks that will raise a red flag if some expressions / keywords are found. Any ideas of what to look for?

**Note:** the files I will be inspecting are relatively small in size (few 100s of lines at most), implementing numerical analysis functions that all operate **in memory**. No external libraries (except math.h) shall be used in the code. Also, no I/O should be used (functions will be run with in-memory arrays).

Given the above, are there some **programmatic** checks I could do to *at least try* to detect harmful code?

**Note:** since I don't expect any I/O, if the code does I/O -- **it is considered harmful**.

Comment: Well, you can check the `#include` directives to see if anything other than a "whitelist" of headers is included.

Comment: Static code analysis. Simply checking for your forbidden functions or any #include that aren't allowed, if anything make a whitelist and check to see if whatever is there is not in your whitelist such as all includes must be math.h, function calls should be to local in file functions or math.h functions etc...

Comment: What is the purpose of the check?  If you run the code as a carefully isolated and under-privileged user, possibly in a `chroot()` jail (if you're on Unix or a derivative), then the code is unlikely to be able to do much damage to your machine.  That may be more problematic if you're on Windows, but there are VMs available and you could isolate your code to a VM (you could do that on Linux too).  Since I/O is harmful, you can have the VM isolated on the network.  However, it is hard to see how a program can be useful without doing I/O in some form.

Comment: @Jonathan: "a single C source file" needn't do I/O to be useful.

Comment: @Rafe, c'mon, you don't need to `#include` stdio.h for example to be able to do file operations. `printf` is there anyway, you just need to declare it :)

Comment: Jonathan, that you -- the idea of running the code in a `chroot()` is good.

Comment: @unkulunkulu, thank you; when we declare `printf` it works -- without needing to import `<stdio.h>`

Comment: Just run it in a sandbox. It's the only (practical) way to be sure.

Comment: On Linux there is also `prctl(PR_SET_SECCOMP)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to make sure it's not calling anything not allowed, then compile the piece of code and examine what it's linking to (say via `nm`).  Since you're hung up on doing this by a "programmatic" method, just use python/perl/bash to compile then scan the name list of the object file.

There's not a lot you can do about buffer overwrites for statically defined buffers, but you could link against an electric-fence type memory allocator to prevent dynamically allocated buffer overruns.

You could also compile and link the C-file in question against a driver which would feed it typical data while running under valgrind which could help detect poorly or maliciously written code.

In the end, however, you're always going to run up against the "does this routine terminate" question, which is famous for being undecidable.  A practical way around this would be to compile your program and run it from a driver which would `alarm`-out after a set period of reasonable time.

**EDIT**: Example showing use of `nm`:

Create a C snippet defining function `foo` which calls `fopen`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
foo() {
   FILE *fp = fopen("/etc/passwd", "r");
}
```

Compile with `-c`, and then look at the resulting object file:

```
$ gcc -c foo.c
$ nm foo.o
0000000000000000 T foo
                 U fopen
```

Here you'll see that there are two symbols in the `foo.o` object file.  One is defined, `foo`, the name of the subroutine we wrote.  And one is undefined, `fopen`, which will be linked to its definition when the object file is linked together with the other C-files and necessary libraries.  Using this method, you can see immediately if the compiled object is referencing anything outside of its own definition, and by your rules, can considered to be "bad".

Comment: Mark, thank you. Can you elaborate on `nm` and how to use it?

Comment: @user3262424 - Updated text two show example use of `nm`.  Also, there are man pages on it (e.g. `man nm`).

Answer (score 8):

Yes, there are programmatic ways to detect the conditions that concern you.

It seems to me you ideally want a static analysis tool to verify that the preprocessed version of the code:

1. Doesn't call any functions except those it defines and non I/O functions in the standard library,
2. Doesn't do any bad stuff with pointers.

By preprocessing, you get rid of the problem of detecting macros, possibly-bad-macro content, and actual use of macros.  Besides, you don't want to wade through all the macro definitions in standard C headers; they'll hurt  your soul because of all the historical cruft they contain.

If the code only calls its own functions and trusted functions in the standard library, it isn't calling anything nasty.  (Note: It might be calling some function through a pointer, so this check either requires a function-points-to analysis or the agreement that indirect function calls are verboten, which is actually probably reasonable for code doing numerical analysis).

The purpose of checking for bad stuff with pointers is so that it doesn't abuse pointers to manufacture nasty code and pass control to it.   This first means, "no casts to pointers from ints" because you don't know where the int has been :-}

For the who-does-it-call check, you need to parse the code and name/type resolve every symbol, and then check call sites to see where they go.  If you allow pointers/function pointers, you'll need a full points-to analysis.

One of the standard static analyzer tool companies (Coverity, Klocwork) likely provide some kind of method of restricting what functions a code block may call.   If that doesn't work, you'll have to fall back on more general analysis machinery like our [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html)
with its [C Front End](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/FrontEnds/CFrontEnd.html).  DMS provides customizable machinery to build arbitrary static analyzers, for the a language description provided to it as a front end.  DMS can be configured to do exactly the test 1) including the preprocessing step; it also has full points-to, and function-points-to analyzers that could be used to the points-to checking.

For 2) "doesn't use pointers maliciously", again the standard static analysis tool companies provide some pointer checking.   However, here they have a much harder problem because they are statically trying to reason about a Turing machine.  Their solution is either miss cases or report false positives.  Our [CheckPointer](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/MemorySafety) tool is a *dynamic* analysis, that is, it watches the code as it runs and if there is any attempt to misuse a pointer CheckPointer will report the offending location immediately. Oh, yes, CheckPointer outlaws casts from ints to pointers :-}  So CheckPointer won't provide a static diagnostic "this code can cheat", but you will get a diagnostic if it actually attempts to cheat.   CheckPointer has rather high overhead (all that checking costs something) so you probably want to run you code with it for awhile to gain some faith that nothing bad is going to happen, and then stop using it.

EDIT: Another poster says *There's not a lot you can do about buffer overwrites for statically defined buffers*.  CheckPointer will do those tests and more.

Comment: There's also the problem of whether a stack overflow and infinite loops would be considered harmful. If so, one would need to add checks for those cases, which can also be pretty tricky. It is not trivial to define "harmful".

Comment: True.  OP already agreed he couldn't get a perfect answer.  He can eliminate stack overflow by insisting on no direct or indirect recursion, which he can detect by building a call graph (DMS does this) and checking for cycles.   Infinite loops is probably harder to stop, but that he can control by building his own timer machinery if he feels nervous.

Comment: Forgot to mention it on my last comment, but limiting the size/number of local function variables(e.g. no int x[10000000];) would probably also be a good idea. I don't mean this to be negative criticism of this answer(which I did upvote), just complementary information.

Comment: Stack overflow by use of too many locals? I suppose that might happen, but when the function gets entered typically it allocates necessary stack space; if it uses a huge amount the program is likely to trap on a page fault immediately.  Still real enough.  A static analysis tool like DMS can be configured to check for outrageously big allocations or rediculous numbers of locals.

Comment: Ira, thank you for the detailed answer. Are these tools free? my answer was directed more towards possible programmatic ideas -- meaning, what I should be looking for programmatically (say, when writing a `python` script) in the `.c` source file.

Comment: Both tools are commercial.  CheckPointer is modestly priced IMHO.  CheckPointer's evaluation version might run your codes if they are small.  DMS is considerably more expensive; the market is much smaller.  But the value is correspondingly greater; you can try to write some kind of checker using a Python script, but you will find out, as many, many others have, that all that machinery that an engine like DMS has is needed to process real languages like C, and that machinery is not easy to build.   People try to get around this by abusing other engines, such as GCC.   Clang is recent choice.

Answer (score 0):

You could do some obvious checks for "bad" function calls like network IO or assembly blocks. Beyond that, I can't think of anything you can do with just a C file.

Given the nature of C you're just about going to have to compile to even get started. Macros and such make static analysis of C code pretty difficult.

Comment: Andrew White, thank you. Is there a good way to identify `Macros`? also, how can I identify `assembly blocks`?

Comment: just look for `#` or if you can use gcc -E which auto expands macros for you.

Comment: thanks Andrew. Can you provide more info on `gcc -E` and how it can help in this case?

Comment: it does more-of-less exactly what I said, it replaces macros with what they evaluate too which well help deobfuscate the code a bit.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a **programmatic** way to identify MACROS in the code?