# compile c/c++ online [security issue]

Tags: php, c++, c, gcc

I'm trying to compile c/c++ program online by gcc compiler.
when user enter c/c++ code,I will make temp file (temp.cpp) and after that I will compile it by

```
 exce('gcc temp.cpp');
```

php function.after that I will run it by `exce()`  function too.
now how can I sure user c/c++ code don't be to hurt my website?how can I prevent to access files,database,killing process and ... that can be done by C/C++ program?

Comment: If you plan to execute the file - unless c++ or gcc have extensive whitelisting or library-excluding abilities that I'm not aware of, this is terribly, terribly dangerous. You would have to run the compiled program in a chroot jail or something. Depending on what operating system you are running this on (and whether you have root access to your server, which you will need) this may be better suitable on serverfault.com or linux.stackexchange.com

Comment: I'd start by a) by being very careful and thinking a lot, and b) by allowing only a very small, restricted set of libraries. But there's lots more to consider beyond that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Harmful C Source File Check?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6810322/harmful-c-source-file-check)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As long as you don't execute the compiled program on your server, it's fine.

If you *do* run the program on your server, then you'll have to sandbox it, which can be difficult. See [codepad's about page](http://codepad.org/about) to see how they do it.