# C File With No #?

Tags: c

Suppose that you are give a single `C source file`, that contains a max. of 300 lines of code.

Suppose also that the file, while implementing several functions, **DOES NOT** contain the character **'#'** in it (meaning, there are NO `#include` statmements, and no other statements that have '#' in the file).

My question is, does the above **guarantee** that the file **does not** do any I/O? does it guarantee that the file **will not** be able to (say) erase the contents of the hard drive, or do other fishy things?

(I am supposed to get 100-200 single `C` files, that (as mentioned) do not include the char `#` in them. I was asked to write a simple program that will **programmatically** check if a single `C source file` with no `#` is potentially involved in I/O, accessing to the network etc).

Given the fact that no statements with `#` are allowed -- what is the WORST code a coder can include in such a `C` file to potentially damage the system of the one who runs it?

I **know** that no check will yield 100% accuracy -- but am interested *at least* to do some basic checks that will raise a red flag if some expressions / keywords are found. Any ideas of what to look for?

Comment: You don't need `#include` to do IO: You could run the preprocessor and output the C code and save that. It is potentially capable of anything, and by definition won't have any # directives.

Comment: 1) 99% of C files include something. 2) There still exist inline assembly.

Comment: mu is too short: yes, just a single `c` source file, defining some functions that operate in-memory.

Comment: davin: `...You could run the preprocessor and output the C code and save that`. Can you please elaborate, perhaps with a brief code / example?

Comment: How many different angles are you going to ask this question about?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6809965/c-print-to-screen-without-include-stdio-h, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6810322/harmful-c-source-file-check

Comment: Joe: this is not the same; here, it is clearly stated that `#` chars are not allowed

Comment: You keep asking this essentially same question, and I think the answer is always that to do this kind of checking properly (to prevent security holes) requires some pretty heavy duty static analysis - not an ad-hoc, quick-n-dirty thing looking for matches to tokens.  You've also had a couple of comments that suggest running your tests in a restricted and/or isolated environment so that it won't matter if the test runs code that tries to perform something malicious. I think you might want to investigate whether that will meet your needs.

Answer (score 12):

No, it can't guarantee that. You can produce the code where all includes and macros are expanded, and you can make it into a single huge file, then compile it... that file, won't contain any preprocessor directive, though it can do anything usually C can do on a system.

Comment: example would not be "small" by definition! just try `gcc -E` if you're using gcc; (there will be still some `#` because of line numbering, though you can eliminate it too)

Comment: of course, since this is just the effortless way for any kind of program... for small program it can be as simple as  `int printf(const char *format, ...);
int main()
{
  printf("hello");
  return 0;
}` works

Answer (score 5):

If the original coder were to include inline assembly, they could do pretty much anything they liked, without importing any libraries.

Comment: CajunLuke, thank you. How can I detect the existance of `inline assembly`?

Comment: It depends on the compiler you're using - gcc vs. Microsoft's C compiler. Here's the first result on Google for `inline assembly gcc`: http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html

Answer (score 5):

One could just copy and paste the definitions of standard file types and functions (e.g. FILE, fopen(), fprintf(), flocse()) etc into a C file. In this way no include is needed and when the file is compiled and linked to the proper libraries, it will be able to perform I/O.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I am looking for. Is there a list somewhere of ALL FUNCTIONS (like `fopen()`, `fclose()` etc) that can do I/O, damage the disk / memory etc?

Comment: If you are using the GNU standard library you might want to look at http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/index.html. But I guess that with the inline assembly trick mentioned by CajunLuke you can perform system calls directly. These vary from operating system to operating system.

Comment: Giorgio, thank you. I am using `Ubuntu Linux`. How does one identify `inline assembly`?

Comment: Giorgio, it looks like `inline assembly` can be easily identified by the keyword `asm`. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, inline assembly blocks are declared using asm or __asm__.

Comment: Giorgio, so it is sufficient to detect using string matching the existence of `asm*` in the code -- if it doesn't exist, and there are no `#include` -- things should be more safe, no? especially if I block other functions like `fopen()` etc.

Comment: @user3262424: I think there are quite a few functions you want to block: stream I/O, low-level I/O, file system interface functions, network, and so on. Btw, what is the use of your C source files if they cannot perform any I/O?

Comment: Giorgio, just some in-memory numerical operation

Answer (score 3):

`#` is not the only token that can start a preprocessor directive. `??=` and `%:` are equivalent definitions in the standard. (But they are not recognized by all compilers.)

Answer (score 2):

C allows unsafe operations with pointers. For example on a system without ASLR it's trivial to get the pointer to arbitrary library functions. It's not very robust since any memory access violation will kill you, but at least if you know the target system it's possible.

ASLR makes it slightly more difficult, but I assume you could just get a pointer to the current position on the stack and then crawl upward until you reach stack belonging to the entry point of your thread. Which will have some interesting pointers for sure.

Comment: Thank you. Can you explain what `ASLR` is?

Comment: Address space layout randomization. Simply put the positions where dlls/libraries are loaded vary so you can't hardcode a pointer to them. Makes writing exploits harder. But in your case it doesn't help much.

Comment: Thanks you. Can you explain how can this `ASLR` damage my system? is it at all relevant in this case?

Comment: I explained that your system is trivially broken without ASLR just hardcode the pointer to an interesting function exported from say `Kernel32.dll` (Using windows as example same applies to other OS). ASLR makes it a bit harder to break your system, but not by much. My main point is that your system is utterly broken.

Comment: I would also be interested to know how you would get a pointer to a library function. Do you compute it relative to the current function? A code snippet would be great, if it is not too complex.

Comment: @Giorgio I assumed that the OP detects static imports. If you can simply import functions from arbitrary dlls it's even easier to break. What I'm trying to say is that if he manages to block everything except pointers and basic plain c it's still broken.

Comment: Yes but do you need some pointer trick? Is it not sufficient to just invoke a function by name? The linker will do the job of finding the address of the function in the appropriate library file.

Comment: I think a simple black list could block that. And without a preprocessor I don't see a way to work around that blacklist. But I'm not a c expert.

Answer (score 2):

Absence of preprocessor directives doesn't guarantee *anything* except the absence of preprocessor directives.

You could still manually add the data types and function prototypes for any library functions you're interested in.  If you're familiar with the underlying platform, you could bypass the standard library entirely and make system calls directly.

Once upon a time I saw code (probably for the IOCCC) that used an array of unsigned char to store raw opcodes and then used type punning to treat it as a function, something like

```
unsigned char instr[] = {0x00, 0x12, 0x33, ...};

void (*foo)(void) = (void (*)(void)) instr;
foo();
```

Note that this relied on undefined behavior and a host of non-portable assumptions, and I'm not even sure such an approach would work anymore.  But if it did, this isn't something that would be easy to catch with a simple source scan.

**EDIT**

I found the code I was thinking of - it was an [IOCCC](http://www1.us.ioccc.org/main.html) entry from 1984. It doesn't work the way I described, though.  Hey, I'm getting old, and stuff isn't sticking to my brain the way it used to.

```
short main[] = {
277, 04735, -4129, 25, 0, 477, 1019, 0xbef, 0, 12800,
-113, 21119, 0x52d7, -1006, -7151, 0, 0x4bc, 020004,
14880, 10541, 2056, 04010, 4548, 3044, -6716, 0x9,
4407, 6, 5568, 1, -30460, 0, 0x9, 5570, 512, -30419,
0x7e82, 0760, 6, 0, 4, 02400, 15, 0, 4, 1280, 4, 0,
4, 0, 0, 0, 0x8, 0, 4, 0, ',', 0, 12, 0, 4, 0, '#',
0, 020, 0, 4, 0, 30, 0, 026, 0, 0x6176, 120, 25712,
'p', 072163, 'r', 29303, 29801, 'e'
};
```

Here's the [explanation](http://www.ioccc.org/1984/mullender.hint):

```
The Grand Prize: 

    Sjoerd Mullender & Robbert van Renesse

Without question, this C program is the most obfuscated C program that
has ever been received!  Like all great contest entries, they result
in a change of rules for the following year.  To prevent a flood of
similar programs, we requested that programs be non machine specific.

This program was selected for the 1987 t-shirt collection.

NOTE: If your machine is not a Vax-11 or pdp-11, this program will
      not execute correctly.  In later years, machine dependent
      code was discouraged.

The C startup routine (via crt0.o) transfers control to a location
named main.  In this case, main just happens to be in the data area.
The array of shorts, which has been further obfuscated by use of
different data types, just happens to form a meaningful set of PDP-11
and Vax instructions.  The first word is a PDP-11 branch instruction
that branches to the rest of the PDP code.  On the Vax main is called with
the calls instruction which uses the first word of the subroutine as a
mask of registers to be saved.  So on the Vax the first word can be anything.
The real Vax code starts with the second word.  This small program
makes direct calls to the write() Unix system call to produce a
message on the screen.  Can you guess what is printed?  We knew you
couldn't!  :-)

Copyright (c) 1984, Landon Curt Noll.
All Rights Reserved.  Permission for personal, educational or non-profit use is
granted provided this this copyright and notice are included in its entirety
and remains unaltered.  All other uses must receive prior permission in writing
from both Landon Curt Noll and Larry Bassel.
```

Again, I don't know if this trick would work on any modern desktop OS, but it would be fun to find out.

Comment: hmmm -- I have never seen such a thing. Thanks for mentioning it.

Comment: I had thought about something like this too, but I wondered if it is allowed by the operating system: the instr variable lives in the data segment while the calling code lives in the code (text) segment. Is it allowed to perform a jump to an address within the data segment? Maybe on certain old operating systems (such as MSDOS) but on more recent ones? I think you would get an exception because you are trying to jump to an address that is not within the code segment. Not sure about this though.

Comment: The data as code stuff won't work with DEP enabled. AFAIK windows supports DEP only on 64 bit processors. @Giorgio thus it won't work in recent OS, but I'm pretty sure it will work in the still popular 32bit WinXP.

Comment: I guess many processors have implemented some mechanism to forbid these kinds of jumps for a long time already (maybe since 80286? or starting from 80386?). But not all operating systems use such mechanisms, thus I would not be surprised if this trick is possible in WindowsXP. I am not an expert though.

Answer (score 1):

not necessicarily. Most compilers generate warnings for implicit declarations, but link in the functions anyway. You can generate a list of io-performing functions, and see if they're called, but that still doesn't preclude inline asm from invoking io-related system calls.

You should probably run with low privlages in a sandbox, and look at what syscalls they make with something like strace.

Comment: Dave, thank you. How can I detect `inline asm`? Also, can you expand on how to use `strace`?

Answer (score 1):

The following program is a valid C program that produces output on `stdout`. It contains no `#` characters:

```
int puts(const char *s);

int main(void)
{
    puts("hi");
    return 0;
}
```

It doesn't even produce a warning from the compiler (`/Wall /W3` on MSVC and `-Wall -Wextra` on MinGW), much less an error.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try compiling the C files into a static binary, disassemble it and check for system call (sysenter, int) instructions. IO cannot be done from userspace and a process will need to go to the kernel to do any kind of IO.

However, this still doesn't protect against execution of instructions in non-text portions of your binary. In the worst case, you may have instructions being fabricated in runtime and executed. For that, I think the best bet is to do code coverage while tracing the process for system calls. Linux has strace which can help with that.

Comment: ritesh: thank you for your response. I gave you an upvote. If not too hard, can you demonstrate with some code how `strace` can be used to identify non-desired parts in the code?

Comment: strace is a linux command line tool [ http://linux.die.net/man/1/strace ]. Instead of running the binary in linux directly just run a program with strace as "strace <command>" and it will let you know about any system calls the process makes.